# Java get hex reversed

Tags: java, file-io, hex, datainputstream

I'm trying to read a file like that:

```
private File infile;
private FileInputStream fis;
private DataInputStream dis;
```

and

```
infile = new File("myfile");
fis = new FileInputStream(infile);
dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
```

Now I want to read a hex like that:

```
int current = dis.readInt();
System.out.println("0x" + Integer.toHexString(current));
```

For anybody who needs it: here are the first bytes of my file

> 3412 aa55 0200 0000

The problem is that my output is `0x3412aa55` but it should be `0x55aa1234`. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Integer.reverseBytes()` to reverse the bytes.

Comment: You mean like Integer.toHexString(Integer.reverse(current))?

Comment: No, this will give me 0xaa55482c

Comment: Got it, I used reverse() instead of reverseBytes()